# Why is reduce not causing a stackoverflow in clojure?

Tags: clojure

Suppose you have this code:

```
(reduce + 1 (range 1 13000))
```

Should this not cause a stackoverflow, because it is not tail call optimized? Or is reduce similar to loop?

Comment: Have you read the source code of `reduce`? What makes you think it is doing non tail calls?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `reduce` will effectively be a loop over the values of the collection.

I say "effectively" because there are actually many different reduce implementation strategies employed by Clojure, depending on the type of the collection. This includes seq traversal via first/next, reduction via iterator, and collections that know how to self-reduce more efficiently.

In this case, the call to `range` actually returns a `LongRange` object which implements the `IReduceInit` interface for self reduction and actually does a tight `do/while` loop (implemented in Java).

The code for this can be found [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/ce55092f2b2f5481d25cff6205470c1335760ef6/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LongRange.java#L229-L238) in the latest release.

Comment: So, instead of recursion, i can use reduce or loop in order to not get a stackoverflow, right?

Comment: Correct, those will work.